# Memory error when unziping a file using PyQGis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I wrote a python script that download a .zip file from internet, then opens it in memory, and write all files I need in a new .zip stocked on hard drive.

But a MemoryError is raised with the biggest file, (300MB uncompressed), could someone help me find out what is wrong?

QGIS version : 2.18.16 - 32 bits

The script :

```
import requests, zipfile

def getZipFromUrl(url):
    data = requests.get(url)
    unzipped = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(data.content))
    del data
    return (unzipped)

def copyZFile(name, origin, dest):
    data = origin.open(name, "r")
    dest.writestr(name, data.read())
    data.close()

def getFile(sdep):
    dir_out = "PLACE OUTPUT PATH HERE"
    dest = zipfile.ZipFile(dir_out+u"/01.zip", "w")
    source = self.getZipFromUrl("http://bano.openstreetmap.fr/BAN_odbl/BAN_odbl_01-shp.zip")
    for filename in bano.namelist():
        if (filename[-4:] != '.txt'):
            self.CopyZFile(filename, source, dest)
```

The error :

```
in copyZFile
    dest.writestr(name, data.read())
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 626, in read
    data = self.read1(n)
File "C:\PROGRA~2\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 680, in read1
    max(n - len_readbuffer, self.MIN_READ_SIZE)
MemoryError
```

I don't understand why I get it, as it works well using python2.7, or smaller files.

Comment: you're loading the whole file into memory. you could try using a streaming/chunking approach, for example the [Python Zipstream library](https://github.com/allanlei/python-zipstream). See also [answers to related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42418071/5158630)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it helped me a lot, unfortunately, even when using streams, I still handle too much data for QGis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to forget about 32 bits version that is limited by Windows with 2GB, and use 64 one instead.

I don't have the error anymore, and thanks to OsGeo4W, I can have both versions installed.

More info on why this limit exists: https://superuser.com/questions/1163749/why-do-32-bit-processes-have-a-2-gb-ram-limit